# Can I take a certain value of a list and append it to another list?

Tags: python

The goal of my code is to be able to read through a log and make a list of the IP Addresses. I've split each line, but am trying to grab the first value [0] of each line to append to a list called IP_Address.

```
IP_Address = []
handle = open("sampleapache_small.log", "rb")
data = handle.readline()
for line in handle:
    return line.split()

#print (IP_Address)
handle.close()
```

Not sure if I can upload the sample apache_small.log file I'm using, but here's a snippet of the data:

[image]

And here is the data when the code is executed (with print instead of return)

[image]

Is it possible to pull the IP address (first value) from the list and append it to a new one?

Comment: `alist.pop(index)`? `new_list.append(old_list.pop(0))`...

Comment: thanks, that's a method I didn't think of!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
IP_Address = []
handle = open("sampleapache_small.log", "rb")
data = handle.readline()
for line in handle:
    IP_Address.append(line.split()[0])

print(IP_Address)
handle.close()
```

Simply access the first value of each line after you split it and append it to a list.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful.